# Is a camera required for animation in blender 2.83?

Tags: camera

Do I need to add a camera to create animations?

Currently I have no camera.

If I don't need one, how is the character viewed later?

[image: Scene tab]

Comment: Of course you'll need  a camera, otherwise Blender won't render

Comment: If I create the charater in blender to be a waiving animation, then give the character to some other software/engine. 
Wouldn't that software set the 'view' depending on the context of their user/software.

Wouldn't blender be saving the movement of the verticies etc and not the user perspective (camera)?

Comment: oh yes sure, you can create your animation without any camera, it's just that at the end, Blender can't render without camera  ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess thats the answer...not sure if I can accept a comment though as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need to render (image or animation) you don't need any camera. If you need to render, of course you need a camera, Blender can't guess what point of view it is supposed to render.